# meaning of "Get the pitch down"

Tags: meaning

> Convincing the CFO often requires speaking the same
>   language—an area of growth for most CIOs. Driving change will
>   partially rely on being able to sell to your primary investors (CFO,
>   CEO, COO, and Board). **Get the pitch down**. Practice and refine.

I think it means fail and then stand. is it true.

Comment: I interpret OP's example as a cut-down version of *Get the **sales** pitch [down **pat**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/have-something-down-pat)* - To know something or be able to do something perfectly.

Comment: Note that *to have something down **pat*** is used in exactly the same way as *...down **to a tee*** - AND plain ***down*** as per the cited example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. "To get something down" is an idiom meaning "[become proficient at something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+%28something%29+down)". At least, that is the case in your example. "Perfect the pitch by practising and refining it".

Another example to help you might be:

"Learning the guitar can seem like a long hard task, but practise, practise and practise some more until **you get it down**".

Answer (score 0):

A **pitch** is a presentation usually to sell something (**pitching** a product).

To **get the pitch down** is to make sure there are no loose ends in the presentation materials and that the presenter will sound confident and not stumble, to "tie it **down**" so it is **secure**.