# To have somebody down, without as

Tags: phrase-meaning

> “but by then she would have them down and whatever they did, it didn’t matter.”

Excerpt From ([*Census*, Jesse Ball](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Z6BMDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT22&dq=%22then%20she%20would%20have%20them%20down%20and%20whatever%20they%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGksmLoODmAhXN5KQKHcelCkYQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22then%20she%20would%20have%20them%20down%20and%20whatever%20they%22&f=false))

"Have them down" means completely figured them out?

Comment: I think it would be a "lucky guess" if anyone managed to derive the exact intended sense here without ***more context***. I've located the source (will edit it into the question text in a mo), but whatever she's doing looks a bit strange anyway (learning how to read / take over the subjects' minds, and thereby synchronize her movements with theirs?). Perhaps it's an alternative to *have them down **pat*** (be able to ***flawlessly*** imitate / understand them). Or perhaps it's *down **under her thumb / under control***.

Comment: That sure helps, thank you.

Comment: Well no-one else has reacted to this question, so I took the trouble to read a page or two of the surrounding context. It seems the narrator's wife is something of a "telepathic mimic", whose "party trick" is to ape someone else's actions in real time. So the intended sense is indeed *to have X down = to know everything [relevant] about X* (specifically here, *know enough about X to be able to flawlessly imitate them*). But having gone that far, I also checked for earlier ELL questions on this usage. As expected, I found that it has been asked at least twice before...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [meaning of "Get the pitch down".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82269/meaning-of-get-the-pitch-down) Also [“Getting something down” in this context.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/232832/getting-something-down-in-this-context/232835#232835)

Comment: (I imply no criticism of you for not being able to find either of those two earlier questions before posting yours; the built-in search facilities on this site aren't very good, even if you ***did*** make an effort to find them! :)